# How do I display data/information with Matlab App Designer?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I would like to display some information to the user via Matlab App Designer's GUI. I am new to this program and can't seem to find a widget that provides what I feel should be a simple function. Am I missing something? Examples would include showing the user:

1. The path of the file that he/she selected
2. Errors such as "No files detected" that are printed in a Matlab script called on by the GUI code.
3. Other print statements in code such as "Done!", etc that will inform the user when a process is complete.

Is there a way to capture the output in the Matlab command line and report these in a window of some sort in the GUI? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TextArea to display information for the user.  Here's how I made a simple example:

1. Drag a button to the app in design view.
2. Drag in a text area also.  I changed the label to Feedback.
3. Select the button and use the Callbacks tab in the bottom right of app designer to add a callback with the default name it gives you.
4. Edit the callback to contain

   ```
       answer = 'what your want to display';
       app.FeedbackTextArea.Value = answer;
   ```

When you push the button the text area gets filled.  In your code, instead of just setting 'answer' to some string, set a variable using whatever code is dealing with your user's information.  The key is to store what you want the user to see in a variable and then assign that to the "Value" parameter of the text area or other widget where you want them to see the results.